# Post_Id ShareDialog always return null in Android

Tags: android, facebook, share

Event show dialog :

```
    ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
    shareDialog.registerCallback(viewModel.callbackManager, viewModel.facebookCallbackShare, REQUEST_SHARE);
    if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
        ShareLinkContent shareLinkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentDescription(description)
                .setContentTitle("title")
                .setQuote(description)
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(link))
                .build();
        shareDialog.show(shareLinkContent, ShareDialog.Mode.FEED);
    }
}
```

And Facebook Callback;
I'm using FacebookCallback with Sharer.Result to listen data callback:

```
    public FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result> facebookCallbackShare = new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        try {
            data.put("post_id", (result.getPostId() != null) ? result.getPostId() : "postID_dang_null");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {

    }
};
```

Code dont show any bug, but also this not return postID . I need postid to update this to api server.

Comment: The `post_id` should only be returned if your app has been granted `publish_actions` permission. See docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/

Comment: Thank Bangdel, 
I have try request approve publish_action, but facebook not approve because my app is only using facebook share is not Open Graph actions. I'm try show dialog show : "post_id is null" ,but facebook not approve it.